# Querying related data from a Django model with 2 or more degrees of separation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

Suppose I have the following Django models:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Staff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Agent(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Writer(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Order(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    writer = models.ForeignKey(Writer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The relationship between the models have the following conditions:

- Each order may only have one client
- Each order may only have one agent
- Each order may only have one writer
- A client may have multiple orders
- An agent may have multiple orders
- A writer may have written multiple orders

Given these models and parameters, how can I get a list of all agents or all writers who have worked with a specific client in the past?

I somehow need to query from [Client] > [All Orders] > [Agent per Order] using Python/Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible way of doing it for all agents for instance :

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(client=client)

agents = []
for order in orders:
    agents.append(order.agent)
```